# How to make ScrollView scroll smoothly

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I want to use RecycleView in ScrollView, but when I do so my scrolling view fixes the moment I stop scrolling. How to make it more smooth?
Here is my xml file used:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"/>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="143dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You don't need a Scrollview around a RecyclerView. It scrolls on its own

Comment: Don't I need to use it for ViewPager?

Comment: I don't think so... A ViewPager just shows horizontal pages. Your RecyclerView is like a ListView. If you put enough data in it, it scrolls.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do so, thanks!